# Issue with sql and inserting guid number

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a table `Users` with columns `UserAccountID` (char), `Username` (varchar), `Password` (varchar).

In ASP.NET MVC I created a form for creating new users, but I don't know how to auto-generate that number. I think that I need some trigger but I'm not sure is that good direction? And I don't know how to pass that number as `UserAccountID` programmatically and for the other two columns whatever the user inputs in text fields?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
[UserAccountID] CHAR (36) NOT NULL,
[Username] VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
[Password] VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserAccountID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: What is your rdbms? Do you know what `autonumeric` [fields](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) are?

Comment: Use auto-increment fields for ids unless you have a good reason not to. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: I know for a-i fields but the task is to use guid, thats the first time i hear of them. Im using that in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can create a new guid in the app by just using

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
```

or let the DB generate it for you with `newsequentialid()` in SQL Server (or some other function depending on what database server you are using), either in the `INSERT` command or as the default value of the column.

I would also consider changing the column type to `uniqueidentifier` instead of `char`.

Comment: DBMS is not specified, and neither is the length of the ID column,

Comment: I got it. You gave me some idea. Thanks